# Partial Mocking with Ecom Dev

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit

I'm trying to partially mock a helper that runs the code below

```
public function formatPostcode($postcode, $country_code) {
        if ( $country_code === "AU" ) {
            return $this->formatAUPostcode($postcode);
        } else {
            return $this->formatGBPostcode($postcode);
        }
    }
```

Test class will contain code as follows:

```
public function testFormatPostcodeWithGBParam() {
       $postcode = "SW12 9ER";
       $helper = $this->getHelperMock('postcodelookup/data', array('formatAUPostcode', 'formatGBPostcode'));

       $helper->expects($this->once())
              ->method('formatGBPostcode')
              ->with($this->equalTo($postcode))
              ->will($this->returnValue("fooBar"));

       $helper->expects($this->never())
              ->method('formatAUPostcode');

       $this->assertEquals('fooBar', $helper->formatPostcode($postcode, "GB"));
   }
```

From this I would expect to be able to mock the methods formatAUPostcode and formatGBPostcode, but when I run this test, $helper->formatPostcode() returns null, and neither of the methods in the class are run, as if that method was mocked itself. Not sure if I'm being stupid in here, or I just don't understand something about EcomDev. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: afaik do all methods return null except you put them into the array, then the mock calls the original method. try removing the methods from the array

Comment: if I do they will return null, I think the solution to this might be to not mock the tested object, even though phpunit allows for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that if you want to use the partial mocking, you can scrap getHelperMock and just us PHPUnit's own getMock() with full name of the class as the attribute. This way only methods specified will be mocked, and others will remain for the testing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following code?

```
$this->replaceByMock('helper', 'postcodelookup/data', $helper);
```

But this will replace the helper if other code like a model try to use the helper.

I tried to simulate your problem but on my setup the original method is called.